# return in the if statment did not show in console, cant see the returns

Tags: javascript

i have a question about my returns in the compare ,
i cant see the rusault in the console.
and ill be happy for advice where i can run codes like that?

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?") 
var computerChoice = Math.random()
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return  "The result is a tie!";
    }
else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (chice2 ==="cissors") {
        return "rock wins"; }
    else{
        return "paper wins";}
}

else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (chice2 ==="rock") {
        return "paper wins"; }
    else{
        return "cissors wins";}
}
else if (choice1 === "cissors") {
    if (chice2 ==="paper") {
        return "cissors wins"; }
    else{
        return "rock wins";}
}
else if (choice1 !="cissors","paper","rock") {
        return "You Are So Funny!!...."; }
};
```

Comment: Did you called the compare function?

Comment: What exactly do You enter to Your console? What does it report?

Comment: Do you ever call `console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));` ?

Comment: I am also getting in my console..

Comment: You also have a typo in `chice2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning, then you have to return to something.

A return statement in a function will return to whatever is on the left hand side of the call to the function.

```
var foo = some_function();
```

If your code isn't in a function, then returning is an error.

If you want to log something to the console, then use `console.log()`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi — huh. Learn something new every day. (Oh well, at least the thing I didn't understand proper was what happens when you do a particular thing that makes no sense!)

Answer (score 0):

You spell choice2 wrong in many places and you have to store returned value to a variable.

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?") 
var computerChoice = Math.random()
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var data = compare(userChoice,computerChoice);

console.log(data);
console.log(compare(userChoice,computerChoice));

function compare(choice1, choice2) {
if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return  "The result is a tie!";
    }
else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 ==="cissors") {
        return "rock wins"; }
    else{
        return "paper wins";}
}

else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 ==="rock") {
        return "paper wins"; }
    else{
        return "cissors wins";}
}
else if (choice1 === "cissors") {
    if (choice2 ==="paper") {
        return "cissors wins"; }
    else{
        return "rock wins";}
}
else if (choice1 !="cissors","paper","rock") {
        return "You Are So Funny!!...."; }
};
```